# What does Visit Number mean in Google Analytics - BigQuery export?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Is `visitNumber the number of times a user visits a site to date?
But in the data (see screenshot below), I'm seeing visit numbers skipped, and the visitorId is also null.

[image: Sample Data][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbWeY.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programing related may be better suited for  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are dealing with Google Analytics exported to BigQuery

If so:

`visitorId` is deprecated (thus nulls) and `fullVisitorId` should be used instead.

> **visitNumber** is an INTEGER that represents session number for the user. If this is the first session, then this is set to 1.
>
> **fullVisitorId** is a STRING that represents unique visitor ID (also known as client ID).

See more at [BigQuery Export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719)